# Is there a way for continous JSLint validation in Notepad++ or any other IDE?

Tags: javascript, notepad++, jslint

Is there a way to make Notepad++ JSLint *.js at every code change?

Like a ongoing validator/compiler?

CTRL + SHIFT + F5 got me unproductive;

Answer (score 1):

In [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/fbzhong/sublime-jslint) to run JSLint whenever you save the file.
[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and other JetBrains IDEs [support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/05/lint-your-javascript-with-jslintjshint-in-real-time/) this too. There is a bunch of [vim](http://www.vim.org/) plugins like [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2578) allowing you to lint your code after buffer save placing warnings to quickfix window.

Not sure about Notepad++ alternative. But there is a plugin called `NppExec` that can be used to run some external command on file save. Another workaround is to just use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to catch `Ctrl+S` shortcut and call another one. Something like this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
^s:: ;Ctrl+S
{
    Send, ^s{F5}
    WinWaitActive, Run...
    Send, {Enter}
    return
}
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: vim comment made my day

Comment: @Ultra could you please try my new suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

If you like `Eclipse`, maybe you can take a look to [JSHint Eclipse 0.9.9](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jshint-eclipse).

[image]